# Flutter ARKit Impose Plane on top of Image

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit

I am using ARKit for flutter via [ARKit_Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin) and want to impose a plane on top of an image using World Tracking as configuration. Something like this:

[image]

I am detecting the image without problems, however, when the plane is placed based on the ImageAnchor found, the plane is always placed wrongly. Anywhere, but where the image is.

I have tried with multiple positions of the ARKitNode plane, such as based on the position and size of the ImageAnchor. This position however is not working. The plane is placed randomly (or it feels like this), even though according to this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-image-recognition/), placing the plane on top of the recognized image should be like the code below.

I would appreciate any help or pointers to this basic AR functionality.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ARKit in Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ARKitSceneView(
            configuration: ARKitConfiguration.worldTracking,
            maximumNumberOfTrackedImages: 1,
            onARKitViewCreated: onARKitViewCreated,
            showStatistics: true,
            showWorldOrigin: true,
            detectionImages: const [
              ARKitReferenceImage(
                name:
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg/800px-OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg',
                physicalWidth: 0.2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  void onARKitViewCreated(ARKitController arkitController) {
    this.arkitController = arkitController;
    this.arkitController.onAddNodeForAnchor = onAddNodeForAnchor;
  }

  void onAddNodeForAnchor(ARKitAnchor anchor) {
    if (anchor is ARKitImageAnchor) {
      final anchorPosition = anchor.transform.getColumn(3);
      ARKitNode planeSuperposition = _createPlane(
        x: anchorPosition.x,
        y: anchorPosition.y,
        z: anchorPosition.z,
        name: 'planeSuperposition',
        width: anchor.referenceImagePhysicalSize[0],
        height: anchor.referenceImagePhysicalSize[1],
      );

      arkitController.add(planeSuperposition);
    }
  }

  ARKitNode _createPlane({
    double x = 0,
    double y = 0,
    double z = 0,
    required String name,
    color = Colors.blue,
    double width = 1,
    double height = 1,
  }) {
    final plane = ARKitPlane(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      materials: [
        ARKitMaterial(
          transparency: 0.5,
          diffuse: ARKitMaterialProperty.color(color),
        )
      ],
    );
    return ARKitNode(
      geometry: plane,
      position: vector.Vector3(x, y, z),
      //rotation: vector.Vector4(1, 0, 0, -math.pi / 2),
      eulerAngles: vector.Vector3(-1 * math.pi / 2, 0, 0),
      //eulerAngles: vector.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      name: name,
    );
  }
```

Unfortunately, using Image Tracking instead of WorldTracking is not helping either. I used the example of [widget projection](https://github.com/olexale/arkit_flutter_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/widget_projection.dart), but with a plane, and in my case it does not work. The plane is simply wrongly placed. Can someone help with the transform?

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ARKit in Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ARKitSceneView(
            configuration: ARKitConfiguration.imageTracking,
            maximumNumberOfTrackedImages: 1,
            onARKitViewCreated: onARKitViewCreated,
            showStatistics: true,
            showWorldOrigin: true,
            trackingImages: const [
              ARKitReferenceImage(
                name:
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg/800px-OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg',
                physicalWidth: 0.2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  void onARKitViewCreated(ARKitController arkitController) {
    this.arkitController = arkitController;
    this.arkitController.onAddNodeForAnchor = onAddNodeForAnchor;
  }

  void onAddNodeForAnchor(ARKitAnchor anchor) {
    if (anchor is ARKitImageAnchor) {
      final anchorPosition = anchor.transform.getColumn(3);
      ARKitNode planeSuperposition = _createPlane(anchor);
      arkitController.add(planeSuperposition);
    }
  }

  ARKitNode _createPlane(ARKitImageAnchor anchor) {
    final width = anchor.referenceImagePhysicalSize.x;
    final height = anchor.referenceImagePhysicalSize.y;
    final t = anchor.transform.clone();
    t.invertRotation();
    t.rotateZ(math.pi / 2);
    t.rotateX(math.pi / 2);

    final plane = ARKitPlane(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      materials: [
        ARKitMaterial(
          transparency: 0.5,
          diffuse: ARKitMaterialProperty.color(Colors.red),
        )
      ],
    );
    return ARKitNode(
      geometry: plane,
      transformation: t,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does the earth sample work for you? https://github.com/olexale/arkit_flutter_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/earth_page.dart

Comment: Hi Olexale! I am a big fan of yours! You did a great job with the ARKit Plugin for Plugin. So in advanced thanks for that. =) 

To your question, yes it does. That example, as the example with NetworkImage. Both work very well, when displaying a Sphere Node or whatever. 

The problem I am facing is when I want to position a plane exactly on top of the AnchorImage.

Comment: Thank you!
I haven't worked with AR for quite a while. From what I see, if you are interested in a more precise anchor position, you will need to subscribe to onUpdateNodeForAnchor callback and update the node's position there. Unfortunately, the plugin is not doing this for you. Without it, it will get the first detected position, which might be distorted and/or inaccurate.

Comment: Great idea! With onUpdateNodeForAnchor works much better. It seems that the first location is not accurate. I think this might be due to not having approapiate light. Good call. Thank you very much. Additionally, can you point to some good tutorial/books to fully understand transform? Ohhh and by the way, have any plans to integrate object recognition in your plugin? (I am willing to give you a hand)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not work on the plugin now. I spend my free time on initiatives that might get more attention so that I can remind the world about the war and the importance of support for my country - Ukraine. I'm still working on PRs, so if you need my help with any new functionality, raise the draft PR with what you've already done.